# 2d animation skins

Tags: game-development, animation

I am making a rather simple mobile app for my kids. This program is written in Flutter.

In this app I would like to create two 2D characters, where each caracter will be able to access different bodyparts (like legs, body and hair).
Since I don't want to make a totally new character for every change they make (that would pretty soon be very many charcters), I was thinking of creating the parts (leg, body and hair) separately and then add them together according to the players choice (like different skins).

My wonder is if any one can help me recommend a good software tool for this project (changing and adding the bodyparts)?

I have looked at a few different programs, but this is all absolutely new to me and I'm very unsure where to begin, so any help is highly appreciated. Thanks